# String manipulation - getting value after the last position of a char

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can get the value after last char(. ; + _ etc.):
e.g.

> string.name+org.com

I want to get "com".
Is there any function in jQuery?

Comment: «after last char»: do you mean after last dot (.) ?

Answer (score 23):

Use `lastIndexOf` and `substr` to find the character and get the part of the string after it:

```
var extension = name.substr(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/K3BWn/

Comment: That was fine until they changed the question to list multiple characters (e.g., not just `.`).

Answer (score 5):

A simple and readable approch to get the substring after the last occurrence of a character from a defined set is to *split* the string with a regular expression containing a character class and then use [**`pop()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop?v=example) to get the last element of the resulting array:

> The `pop()` method removes the last element from an array **and returns that element**.

See a JS demo below:

```js
var s = 'string.name+org.com';
var result = s.split(/[.;+_]/).pop();
console.log(result);
```

to split at all non-overlapping occurrences of the regex by default.

**NOTE**: If you need to match `^`, `]`, `\` or `-`, you may escape them and use anywhere inside the character class (e.g. `/[\^\-\]\\]/`). It is possible to avoid escaping `^` (if you do not put it right after the opening `[`), `-` (if it is right after the opening `[`, right before the closing `]`, after a valid range, or between a shorthand character class and another symbol): `/[-^\]\\]/`.

Also, if you need to split with a single char, no regex is necessary:

```js
// Get the substring after the last dot
var result = 'string.name+org.com'.split('.').pop();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

Not jQuery, just JavaScript: <s>[`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) would do it</s> *(not since the update indicating multiple characters)*. As would a regular expression with a capture group containing a character class followed by an end-of-string anchor, e.g. `/([^.;+_]+)$/` used with [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) or [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

E.g. ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/orokep) | [source](http://jsbin.com/orokep/edit)):

```
var match = /([^.;+_]+)$/.exec(theStringToTest),
    result = match && match[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var s  = "string.name+org.com",
    lw = s.replace(/^.+[\W]/, '');

console.log(lw) /* com */
```

this will also work for
string.name+org/com
string.name+org.info

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RegExp Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Try this code:

```
 "http://stackoverflow.com".replace(/.*\./,"");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw in a *crazy* (i.e. no RegExp) one:

```
var s = 'string.name+org.com';
var a = s.split('.'); //puts all sub-Strings delimited by . into an Array
var result = a[a.length-1]; //gets the last element of that Array
alert(result);​
```

**EDIT**: Since the update of the question is demanding mutiple delimiters to work this is probably not the way to go. Too *crazy*.....

Comment: That was fine (other than the bunch of unnecessary temporary objects) until they changed the question to have multiple characters, not just `.`.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript function like

```
url.substr(url.length - 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is too late to consider, this codes works fine for me using jquery

```
var afterDot = value.substr(value.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
```

You could just replate '_' to '.'

```
var myString = 'asd/f/df/xc/asd/test.jpg'
var parts    = myString.split('/');
var answer   = parts[parts.length - 1];
console.log(answer);
```

Comment: var myString = 'asd/f/df/xc/asd/test.jpg'
var parts = myString.split('/');
var answer = parts[parts.length - 1];