# JS get the last dot of a string and return the string after it

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this RegExp below working. But the return is `True` or `False`. What I want here is to get the last DOT of a string and return the last string after the DOT. As example below I have `image.jpeg.jpeg` I want to return the last `jpeg`. I also try `g.match(x)` but it gives me an error. `g.match is not a function`

```js
var x = "image.jpeg.jpeg"
var g = /(.*)\.(.+)/;
alert(g.test(x));
```

Comment: `x.substr(x.lastIndexOf('.')+1, x.length)`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839445/string-manipulation-getting-value-after-the-last-position-of-a-char

Comment: @Rayon what is the purpose of the x.length there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `split` method like so:

```js
var x = "image.jpeg.jpeg";
var ans = x.split('.').pop();
console.log(ans);
```

Comment: .pop gets the last split?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var x = "image.jpeg.jpeg"
var g = /(.*)\.(.+)/;
alert(x.match(g)[2]);
```

match is a method of String (not RegExp), it's argiment RegExp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var matches = x.match(g);

if (matches.length === 0) {
  console.log('Error');
  return;
}

var last = m[m.length - 1]

alert(last);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```js
var x = "image.jpeg.jpeg"
var g = /\.([0-9a-z]+)$/i;
console.log(x.match(g)[0]); //with a dot
console.log(x.match(g)[1]); //extension only
```